Prove that $\frac{\ln(1+ax)}{\ln(1+bx)}$ is increasing for $a,b>0$ and $a<b$
I want to prove that the fuction $f$ defined in $(0,+\infty)$ by $f(x)=\frac{\ln(1+ax)}{\ln(1+bx)}$ is increasing for every $a,b>0$ and $a<b$.
I tried to calculate the derivative but I don't know how to find it's sign
$$f'(x) = \frac{\frac{a}{1+ax} \ln(1+bx) - \frac{b}{1+bx} \ln(1+ax)}{(\ln(1+bx))^2}$$
I also tried to prove $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}<1$ for every $x<y$ but it didn't give me any result
Could you please give me a hint?

It's enough to prove that $g(x) = \ln f(x) = \ln \ln (1+ax) - \ln \ln (1+bx)$ is increasing.
We have $g'(x) = \frac a{(1+ax)\ln (1+ax)} - \frac b{(1+bx)\ln (1+bx)}$. Since $x>0$, $g'(x)$ is positive if and only if $x g'(x)$ is positive, and we can write $x g'(x)$ as $h(1+ax) - h(1+bx)$, where $h(x) = \frac{x-1}{x \ln x}.$ So it suffices to show that $h(x)$ is decreasing.
We have $h'(x) = \frac{1-x+\ln x}{(x \ln x)^2}$. The denominator is always positive, and $\ln x < x-1$ follows because $\ln x$ is concave and $x-1$ is the tangent line to $\ln x$ at $(1,0)$. Therefore $h'(x) < 0$ for all $x>0$, so $x g'(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$, so $g(x)$ is increasing, so $f(x)$ is increasing.

As you get
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{a}{1+ax}\ln(1+bx)-\frac{b}{1+bx}\ln(1+ax)}{(\ln(1+bx))^2}
=\frac{a(1+bx)\ln(1+bx)-b(1+ax)\ln(1+ax)}{(1+ax)(1+bx)(\ln(1+bx))^2}
,$$
we let $$g(x)=a(1+bx)\ln(1+bx)-b(1+ax)\ln(1+ax),\quad x\geq0,$$
then $$g'(x)=ab[\ln(1+bx)-\ln(1+ax)]>0,\quad \forall x>0.$$
So $g(x)>g(0)=0,\forall x>0$. This implies that $f'(x)>0,x>0$.
Hence the function $f$ is increasing.
